# Missing 'Request Feedback' on Azure DevOps work items?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

On my work items in Azure DevOps Service, I cannot see 'Request Feedback' as an item. I only see 'Do exploratory testing' - What am I missing?

Comment: What are you looking to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to make sure that the [Test & Feedback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/perform-exploratory-tests?view=azure-devops) extension is installed.

**Note**: the Test & Feedback extension is currently available for Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox version 50.0 and higher. Edge support is planned. So you need to choose the right browser to install. You can refer to the "Which web browsers does the extension support?" section of the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/reference-qa?view=azure-devops#browser-support).

Second, you need to pay attention to: Only users with Basic access can request feedback. This is illustrated in this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/request-stakeholder-feedback?view=azure-devops).

After satisfying the above conditions, the "Request Feedback" option should be displayed normally.
[image]

Comment: It looks like there is another non-obvious thing you need to mention. Perhaps, only Stakeholders can create Feedback Response work items. If you request a feedback from a regular (Basic) user, the user interface of a Test & Feedback tool won't show the Provide feedback button - instead of it, you will see Create bug/Create task buttons. See this article (point 5): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/provide-stakeholder-feedback?view=azure-devops